# How can I set ... Windows 8 & Ubuntu 12.04(LTS) Dual Boot: Windows 8 as default OS

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, boot, grub

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 (LTS) on my laptop with Windows 8 already installed. The installation was successfull and I get to use Ubuntu alongside Windows 8. When i start Windows 8 it shows the following error:

```
error: unknown filesystem.
grub rescue>
```

What can I do to fix this?